# AttributeSet for Custom View in Fragment

Tags: android, view, fragment, device-orientation

I have a class Bubble that extends View.  I need to use it in my Fragment which layout file looks like below (note that my Bubble view is showing in this layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffcc33">

    <!-- ***** note that since I am here loading my Bubble class that extends View, that class
         c-tor must take Context AND AttributeSet, otherwise loading this will crash.
         See Bubble c-tor below *****
         -->
    <study.android.bubble.Bubble
        android:id="@+id/bubbleAnimationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff1122"
        android:padding="20dp"/>

    <!-- since parent is FrameLayout, this view will be stacked up in z-order -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:background="@null"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

My custom view Bubble's constructor looks like this:

```
public class Bubble extends View {

    public Bubble(Context context, AttributeSet attributesSet) {
        super(context, attributesSet);
        ...
        ...
    }

    // drawing methods
    ...
    ...
}
```

When I want to instantiate it from my fragment, say in onAttach(), how to I pass it AttributeSet?

Thanks,

Comment: You really need to pass a AttributeSet? I mean, you use it in your custom view class?

Comment: Have you seen my comment in layout file?